Tools that support "in_memory" as an output location
I am trying to write a script where part of it writes a feature class to the "in_memory" workspace.
in_fc = r"path to my fc"
in_memory_fc = r"in_memory\my_fc"

arcpy.Copy_management(in_fc, in_memory_fc)

However this errors out, with a message ERROR 000260: Failed to copy <my path> into <my in_memory path>
When I click on the link to ERROR 000260 it says (amongst other things) the following1:

The "in_memory" workspace is not supported as the output location.

I had to find a different Copy tool that does support the "in_memory" workspace as an output location (the Copy Features tool worked).
So I have been looking for a definitive list of tools that either support or don't support writing to the in_memory workspace.
My question is: Where can I find such a list, possibly in Esri's ArcGIS Desktop documentation website?  If there isn't one readily available, can we create one here?  I am referring only to out of the box standard ArcGIS Desktop tools you'll find in ArcToolbox

Notes:

Yes I know this link is to ArcGIS Pro docs and not ArcMap, but that's because I haven't been able to find the same error message info on the Desktop help site.  It's probably there, but I can't find it.  When I click the link from within ArcCatalog it opens the built-in help file.


I can't answer your question (personally I don't think that list exists), but I'll point out that the Copy_management tool is sort of special in the fact that in can take in so many different types and well, copy them elsewhere. (features, rasters, tables, full datasets, etc). That tool is almost like a windows copy-paste

@KHibma "copy them elsewhere" - except to memory :)

@KHibma Am I likely to find other tools that won't write to in_memory?  If that's the case then I may create a community wiki answer here for people to add to

Absolutely. The caution note here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm talks about a bunch of datasets you can't write to in_memory, which by extension are certain types/groups of tools. But those are sort of obvious, right? You're probably looking for more of the unexpected cases...

@KHibma Right, looking for the not-so-obvious unexpected ones.  Thanks
